# How do I add n number of input fields depending on a passed value?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to create a dynamic number of HTML input text fields, where the number comes posted from another form. But Flask interprets the form number `10` as `1 0`, i.e. `2` (string length).

The first form:

```
<form action="/new_vocals" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="count">
  <input type="submit">
```

The Flask app route:

```
@app.route("/new_vocals", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def new_vocals():
voc_count = request.form['count']
return render_template("new_vocals.html", count=voc_count)
```

Trying to use `voc_count` in a `for` loop, I get 2 input types with the value `10`, 3 with `100` and so on.

There has to be a way to get Flask to interpret `10` as a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float()` to parse your `voc_count` variable (which is a string) as a number, and then use `int()` to further convert it to an integer value.  Once you've done that, you should be able to base a `for` loop around the value of `voc_count`.

```
voc_count = int(float(request.form['count']))
```

Comment: I get the response "'int' object is not iterable" when using a for loop on the variable. Any other suggestions on how to accomplish the same task? I guess there are tons of ways using Javascript but I hardly know Python..

Comment: Hmm, have you tried it as a `float` variable? Can't imagine that would work if `int` doesn't, but who knows? Did you take a look at the [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int) answers?